# How do I show this statement about convergence in filters?

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, projection, filters, product-space

I have the following problem:

> Let $\{(M_i,\tau_i)\}_{i\in I}$ be nonempty topological spaces where $I$ is arbitrary but non empty. Let $M=\prod_{i\in I} M_i$. Let $F$ be a filter on $M$ and denote by
>
> $$F_i=(pr_i)_*F=\{B\subseteq M_i: \exists\,\,A\in F\,\,s.t.\,\,pr_i(A)\subseteq B\}$$ the corresponding image filter on each componente $M_i$. Show that $F$ converges to $p\in M$ iff $F_i$ converges to $p_i=pr_i(p)$ for all $i\in I$.

Then $\Rightarrow$ implication worked perfectly by using some theorem from the lecture. But I somehow struggled a bit with the other implication. In the solution they did something with subbasis ect but I didn't understand that. Therefore I wandet do do it different. My Idea was the following:

$\Leftarrow$ Let us assume tat $F_i$ converges to $p_i$. We need to show that $F$ converges to $p$, i.e. we need to show that $\mathfrak{U}(p)\subset F$ where $\mathfrak{U}(p)$ is the neighbourhood filter of $p$. Now let us take any basis open set $B$ in M. $$B=\bigcap_{i\in I} pr_i^{-1}(O_i)$$where $I$ is finite and $p_i\in O_i$ are open sets in $M_i$. We see that it is enought to show that $pr_i^{-1}(O_i)\in F$. To do so let us use that $F_i\rightarrow p_i\Leftrightarrow \mathfrak{U}(p_i)\subset F_i$. But then $O_i\in (pr_i)_*F$ which implies that there is some $A_i\in F$ such that $pr_i(A_i)\subset O_i$. This implies that $A_i\subset pr_i^{-1}(O_i)\in F$. Then since the intersection is finite also $B\in F$.

Now what I don't see is why then $\mathfrak{U}(p)\subset F$.

I'm really not sure if this workes therefore it would be nice if someone could take a look at it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $O$ be a subbasic element in the product i.e. $O=\pi_i^{-1}[U]$ for some $i \in I$ and some open $U \subseteq X_i$ (I use $\pi_i$ for the projections), so that $p \in O$ i.e. $p_i \in U$.

As by assumption $(\pi_i)_\ast(\mathcal{F}) \to p_i$ we know that $U \in (\pi_i)_\ast(\mathcal{F})$ so for some $F_i \in \mathcal{F}$, $\pi_i[F_i] \subseteq U$, which implies $F_i \subseteq O$ and hence $O \in \mathcal{F}$ as $\mathcal{F}$ is a filter.

So all subbasic elements in the product that contain $p$ are in the filter, and so all *basic* elements (which are the **finite** intersections of such subbasic sets) also are, and hence $\mathcal{F}\to p$, as required.

Comment: Hello @hennobrandsma, thank you for your answer. In the meantime I did it in a different way which looks quite similar to yours but not exaclty. I will update de post above with my new approach. Could you maybe take a look at it?

Comment: Does this works?

Comment: @aprozz it’s essentially the same as my proof. Key is the form of basic open sets and their essential use of only finitely many coordinates. It fits nicely with filter properties.

Comment: But why exaclty do I can conclude that $\mathfrak{U}(p)\subset F$? that's the point I didn't see at the moment

Comment: @aprozz because we have a base for the neighbourhoods. If $U$ is an arbitrary neighbourhood of $p$, it contains a basic one as a subset. The basic one is in the filter, as we saw, so $U$ as well (superset sxiom of filters). It’s sufficient to show that subbasic or basic neighbourhoods are in the filter for convergence proofs. That’s why bases and subbases are convenient.

Comment: aha perfect thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to be a bit careful with the details here. When you write $U=\prod_{i \in I} O_i$, it is not true that every open set of $M$ is of this form. Rather, you can show that given a neighborhood $p \in U$, there are some open sets $p_i \in O_i \subseteq M_i$, **all but finitely many equal to $M_i$**, such that $U \supseteq \prod_{i \in I} O_i$. (This is essentially the claim that the $\mathrm{pr}_i^{-1}(O_i)$ form a subbasis of the product topology on $M$.) Now, the convergence tells you that $O_i \in F_i$, which implies that some set $B_i \subseteq M$ has $\mathrm{pr}(B_i)=O_i$. Here you can asusme that $B_i=\mathrm{pr}_i^{-1}(O_i)$ by the monotonicity of the filter, and then this intersection (which is finite!) tells you that $U \in F$.

Comment: ah okei so I need to work with the subbasis? So I don't really see when we exaclty need the subbasis and when we don't. Could you maybe explain this a bit

Comment: The thing is, the topology of $M$ is usually compued from the subbasis, and so there are not a lot of ways of working with open subsets of $M$. So yeah, I think it is useful to think on this with the subbasis

Comment: so would you always work with the subbasis when we do something with the product topology?

Comment: In addition could you maybe shortly explain if I know that $$S=\{pr_i^{-1}(O_i):O_i\in \tau_i\}$$ is the subbasis of $\tau$. how exaclty does an open set looks like? is it only the finite intersection of elements of the subbasis? Because that's a point I don't see yet